# How to transform a tkinter ListBox into a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter ListBox with, of course, a certain amount of items stocked on it.

I need to save a .txt file with the information stocked on the ListBox.

I've tried many ways but it won't work. Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "stocked"? Do you want the text from all of the entries of the ListBox, or the text from all of the selected entries?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Tkinter.Listbox.get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.get-method) and [`Tkinter.Listbox.curselection()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.curselection-method).

If you want all of the entries from the listbox, try this:

```
print self.lb.get(0,Tkinter.END)
```

If you want the selected entries:

```
print [self.lb.get(i) for i in self.lb.curselection()]
```

Fleshing out the example:

```
# UNTESTED

# Assuming you have an event bound to "OnClick":
def OnClick(self):
  with open("savefile.txt", "w") as savefile:
    # Assuming your listbox is stored in "self.lb"
    savefile.write('\n'.join(self.lb.get(i) for i in self.lb.curselection())
    savefile.write('\n')
```